# set initial page with Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know this has been asked before, but I just cannot get this to work for some reason.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Name("KendoGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
     ---Columns---
    })
    .Events(e=>e.DataBound("onRowBound"))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true).PageSizes(true).ButtonCount(5))
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(20)
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ModelId))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller").Data("Handler"))
        )
     .AutoBind(false)
 )
```

Since my AutoBind is false, I call a function to read the data source after the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     ReadDataSource();
});


function ReadDataSource() 
{
    $("#KendoGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.page(2);
}
```

(I am hard-coding the initial page number for now for simplicity.  Suffice it to say that the data source has at least three pages).

Every time I navigate to the page, it always shows page one.  What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How's your request's response data looks like ? Can you add it ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: If your code perform an ajax *request*, it will have a *response* which can have *data* in it. But nevermind.

Comment: Data is populating just fine.  It is just not going to the correct page of data.

Comment: Paging in kendo is totally related to the data it is getting from server. That is why I've asked.

Comment: There is way too much response data to post.  Since the page size is 20, it is showing a json array with 20 objects, but a total of 55 (since there are three pages).  This seems to be operating properly.

Comment: Well, ok then..

Comment: @RichardMartin Since your AutoBind is false, when do you actually fire the event to fetch data. For ex. `dataSource.read()`. Also. can you remove your AutoBind property and check if my code is giving you an expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your ReadDataSource function to this

```
function ReadDataSource() 
{
    $("#KendoGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(2);
}
```

Comment: This had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function ReadDataSource() 
{
    var grid = $("#KendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.one("dataBound", function () {
        this.dataSource.page(2);
    });
}
```

or

```
// Make sure you set the correct pageSize

function ReadDataSource() 
{
    $("#KendoGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.query({ page: 2, pageSize: 20 });
}
```

Comment: Copy-paste the code in Console window of your browser and see if its actually changes page. Do you see any errors?

Comment: It is definitely not changing the page.  No errors.